# Redirect all joomla pages to .html via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

in my joomla 2.5 installation I've installed mijosef, but after doing it if I go to www.mywebsite.com/name it gives me back error 404.
If I go to www.mywebsite.com/name.html, it's ok.
The support tells me that I can handle this problem via htacces, but i've tried the solution found here and in other forum, without success.

I tried to insert this code:

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1.html [L,R=301]
```

But nothing changes.
How can I solve this?

Thanks

Edit: 
This is my htaccess (i removed the initial parts with #)

```
##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but why are you trying to redirect requests to .html pages for a PHP based CMS website. You will always get an error.

Comment: @BrianBolli the .html pages are ok. Only the pages without any extensions give back error 404.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)? /$1.html
```

and see

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. All the files without .html give back error 400.